# creating a wrong NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, nsdate

This is the code

```
  NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  [comps setDay:13];
  [comps setMonth:6];
  [comps setYear:2015];

  NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                           initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
  NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```

the result is `2015-06-12 23:00:00 +0000`

12? the day is 13!!!

Why is that happening? Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way `NSLog()` and the `NSDate` `description` method display the date which is in GMT (UTC). Notice the time offset: "+0000" which is probably not your timezone.

All dates are stored internally in GMT. To obtain a string in the current or another time zone use `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: This is Apple always doing it in an intuitive way. Thanks!

Comment: You can set the `NSCalendar` instance's timezone to UTC if that's what you want.

Comment: Yeah, key point is: *NSLog is for debugging*. What different objects log is undocumented and therefore version dependent. It's not something you ever show to a user. So `NSDate` can log any way it likes, and is being fully explicit about deciding to log in GMT via the `+0000`. You don't even need the "all dates are stored internally in GMT" fact; it's basically none of your business how they're stored.

Comment: Sure, you don't need to know how Apple stores dates but Apple actually states that dates are stored as: "the absolute reference date used by NSDate (the first instance of 1 January 2001, GMT)". But it does help to understand that dates are not stored in the user's local timezone.

Comment: `NSLog()` is primarily for logging, *not* for debugging. (That's, why it is called `NSLog()`). In logs it is usually useful to have a world-wide defined time.

Comment: Of course it is a little deeper than that as `NSLog()` just uses the `description` method which should only be used for debugging/logging. So it is the `description` method that determines how `NSData` objects are logged.